# Python: Converting a string to an integer

Tags: python, string, int

I need to convert a string from a file that I have into an integer.  The string in question is just one number.

```
L= linecache.getline('data.txt', 1)
L=int(L)  

print L
```

I receive the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xef\xbb\xbf3\n'
```

How do I convert this string into an integer?

Comment: @MattBall No duplicate at all. What you linked has nothing to do with the unexpected BOM which bothers the author of this question.

Answer (score 5):

The file contains an UTF-8 BOM.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.BOM_UTF8
'\xef\xbb\xbf'
```

[`linecache.getline`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline) does not support encoding.

Use [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
with codecs.open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    L = next(f)
    L = int(L)
    print L
```

Answer (score 4):

Your file starts with a [BOM](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). Strip it before trying to parse the number.